# Merge Camera and AudioListener feeds into a video in Unity for OpenCV

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a simulated environnement using Unity3D. My first goat is to fetch the camera and audiolistener feeds and merge / convert it into a readable video. Once I get this, I want to send this to OpenCV.

To do so, I have created a scene with a camera and an object that emit a constant noise. Then, I have attached this script to the camera to catch the feeds :

```
private Texture2D texture;
private byte[] lastTexture;
private float[] lastAudio;


private void Start () 
{
    texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
}

/// <summary>
/// Called each time the camera have finished rendering the scene.
/// </summary>
private void OnPostRender()
{
    // Read the pixel of the camera.
    texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0, true);

    // Encode it to PNG.
    lastTexture = texture.EncodeToJPG(25);

    // Audio sync => fetch the last recorded audio.
    var encodedLastAudio = ConvertAudio(lastAudio);

    // TODO merge and convert to mpeg then send via UDP.
}

/// <summary>
/// Raises the audio filter read event.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data">Data.</param>
/// <param name="channels">Channels.</param>
private void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
{
    lastAudio = data;
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the data recieved by the AudioFilterRead event into a byte array.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The audio.</returns>
/// <param name="dataSource">Data source.</param>
private byte[] ConvertAudio(float[] dataSource)
{
    // Converting in 2 steps : float[] to Int16[], 
    // then Int16[] to Byte[].
    var intData = new Int16[dataSource.Length];

    // BytesData array is twice the size of
    //dataSource array because a float converted in Int16 is 2 bytes.
    var bytesData = new Byte[dataSource.Length*2];

    // To convert float to Int16
    var rescaleFactor = 32767f; 

    for (var i = 0; i < dataSource.Length; i++)
    {
        intData[i] = (short)(dataSource[i]*rescaleFactor);
    }
    Buffer.BlockCopy(intData, 0, bytesData, 0, bytesData.Length);

    return bytesData;   
}
```

Am I doing it right ? If so, I have already looking for C# implementation of ffmpeg like :

- ffmpeg.net
- ffmpeg-sharp
- fflib.net

but I think it is a bit complicated and it will have a massive cpu usage.
Did someone managed to do so, or something alike ?

I already know how to add a wav header to my audio feeds thanks to another thread.

Comment: Instead of using complicated libs and, probably, encounter Unity engine limits, you can use external game capture tools like Nvidia Gamestream of Fraps to this objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the camera and audiolistener of unity is to stream it using VLC.

VLC have a feature where you can stream your own desktop, encoding it and send it via UDP.
The only "catch" with this is that you will have some latency (like 2-3 seconds).